# Is it possible to restore mysql database with mysqldump and keep the same database file size?

Tags: mysql, cron, database-backups

I was restoring MySQL database using cron. The Backup happens successfully but when I check the size, The backup file size is 20B while the original database is bigger than that. Can anyone advise me on how i can have similar database size?

I used this crontab:

0 */3 * * * mysqldump -u root -p[mydb_password] Db_name| gzip -c > /var/backups/file.sql.gz

Comment: The gzip filesize cant have the same size from the database file. But 20B ost to small. It looks like that inly a error message is dumped. Unpack the gz file and look into the file

Comment: Yes @BerndBuffen. It's very small. The unpacked file is empty (0KB). Any idea how I can handle this?